# Casting Any to Tuple2

Tags: scala, casting, tuples

I have a Scala function which passes message of type 'Any'. In most cases it will be a tuple of size 2. The function that receives this message needs to see the specific types of the tuple elements:

```
main() {
// call to function
// msg is of type Any.
    func (msg) 
}
```

Now in my function,

```
function (msg : Any) {
    String inputType = msg.getClass.getCanonicalName
    if (inputType.compareTo("scala.Tuple2") == 0) {
        // I now know that the input to the function is a tuple..I want to extract the type of each element in this tuple.
        //something like:
        var tuple = msg.asInstanceof(scala.Tuple2) // This line gives an error. I want to cast object of Type Any to a tuple.
        var 1type = tuple._1.getClass.getCanonicalName
        var 2type = tuple._2.getClass.getCanonicalName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you just use [pattern matching](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120)?

```
def function(msg: Any) = {
  msg match {
    case tuple @ (a: Any, b: Any) => tuple
  }
}
```

Comment: sweet and simple.. New to the language.. so didn't knw about this feature.. worked perfectly..

Comment: @DeeptiJain enjoy discovering more and more sweetness of this language :)

Answer (score 0):

pattern matching

```
msg match {
   case (x,y) =>  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with this answer after testing using Scala Build Tools version sbt-0.13.8

```
   def castfunction(msg: Any):Tuple2[Char,Int] = {
      msg match { case (x: Char,y:Int) => Tuple2(x,y) }
   }
```